# Processing relational tables without database server

Tags: java, mongodb, database, nosql

Here is my problem, I have:

- One partner that send me the content of his relational database as files that each contains the row of one table
- One partner to which I should send the data through an API that only accept a fully constructed object

Because the tables have 1:n relationships I can't process the content of the files row by row and also the files are way too big (hundred of GB) for using a full in-memory solution and I also will have multiple processes working concurrently to do this conversion (for redundancy and performances). I wish to avoid using an intermediary relational database for this, but I do have access to a MongoDB database.

Do you have any idea on the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that run in a similar problem. We only have the solution for one-to-many relationship but I'm sure this can be extended to other relationships.

Our solution was to process the files a first time and collection information about how many elements share the same foreign key by foreign key values (we do this in a Map in-memory). Then we process the file a second time and put elements of the many part of the relationship into groups by foreign key into the database, when we have all the elements we wait for the element of referenced foreign key (the one part of the relationship) to show up and when it's there we add the information of the other table to all the element that we then group by the foreign key of the referenced table.

We repeat this process multiple times to obtain elements of the furthest tables with the information of all the tables before them. Similar to what you get when you do join on SQL database. We can them regroup those final elements the way we want to be able process them (and send the infos we want to an API).